# javascript get rid of commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I convert timestamp to readable format in below mentioned way and want to display the date without commas.

```
var timestamp = reg_date,
date = new Date(timestamp * 1000),
datevalues = [
               date.getFullYear(),
               "-",              
               date.getMonth()+1, 
               "-",                
               date.getDate()                 
];

block.html('<hr>' + 'Date: ' + datevalues);
```

but it displays it like this

```
2015,-,1,-,11
```

Could you please help me to get rid of commas?

Comment: datevalues.replace(/,/g, "");

Comment: @webkit — `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Arrays don't have a `replace`method.

Comment: @Quentin block.html('<hr>' + 'Date: ' + datevalues); in this line datevalues is already a string..

Comment: Of course joining the array before hand is the appropriate solution though.

Comment: @webkit — It is not already a string. You can see it is defined as an array. It won't become a string until it is evaluated in the context of `+` which will implicitly call `toString()` on it. If you were to stick a call to `replace` on it, then that would be evaluated before the `+`.

Comment: you can use datevalues.split(',').join();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function will do that for arrays, like this `datevalues.join('')`

Or you could do this:

```
datevalues = [
               date.getFullYear(),
               date.getMonth()+1,  
               date.getDate()                 
];
datevalues.join('-');
```

Comment: thanks, I will accept this answer once the system allows